# I dont understand the solution of system of equations

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

I am designing a high pass RLC filter with a pole at $60$ Hz and a cutoff frequency of $50$ Hz.

I end up with this system of equations:

$$\begin{align} y \cdot z &= \frac{1}{3600} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &= \left | \frac{x+50iy}{x+50iy-i\frac{1}{50z}} \right |\end{align}$$

[When I plug the system of equations into Wolphram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=systems%20of%20equations%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22y*z%3D1%2F3600%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf2EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%221%2Fsqrt%282%29%20%3D%20abs%28%28x%2B50iy%29%2F%28-i%2F%2850z%29%2Bx%2B50iy%29%29%22) I get a solution in the complex plane and I don't understand how this is possible since the absolute value of a **complex** number is a **real** number. Why is this happening?

Comment: Were you expecting real numbers as solutions? Since you have a complex number quotient in the modulus, I'm probably looking for complex numbers.

Comment: You have two (complex) equations and three (presumably complex) variables. Which unknowns are you solving for?

Comment: If you involve complex numbers, the solutions of an equation could be complex even when the absolute value is real. For example $|z|=1$ has an infinity of complex solutions: all the unit circle. The fact that the absolute value is real has nothing to do with the existence of complex solutions.